# How to call WCF service via gateway

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf

I have to call a WCF service "https://api-secure.service.com/v1" But not directly rather the request will go through my gateway. which makes the URL something like this "https://fpggateway.com/xml.ashx?c=Core.Network.SslProxy&url=https://api-secure.service.com/v1"

I am trying following code but its not working. Can someone guide what I am doing wrong?

```
var binding = new BasicHttpsBinding();
var endpoint = new EndpointAddress(new Uri("https://fpggateway.com/xml.ashx?c=Core.Network.SslProxy&url=https://api-secure.service.com/v1"));

ConsoleApp1.service.IASServicesClient proxy = new service.IASServicesClient(
new BasicHttpsBinding(),
endpoint);
var response = proxy.CreateAccount(createAccountRequest);// CreateAccount method call
```

Comment: Your **Url** Address:**This URL of yours: http://fpggateway.com/xml.ashx?c=Core.Network.SslProxy&url=https://api-secure.service.com/v1**, it has a query string, so it can't be added as a baseaddress using this method. I think you need to use **asp.net core+Ocelot** to achieve the functionality you need. This is the relevant documentation:[Implement API Gateways with Ocelot](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/microservices/multi-container-microservice-net-applications/implement-api-gateways-with-ocelot)